# Opp close date month should be greater than today month

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, opportunity, validation-rule, closedate

I have a query "users want to restrict the Opportunity for everyone So that no one can mark as closed won until that Opportunity does not contain at least 1 Opportunity Product and the closed date is greater than current month then only Salesforce users can mark."

I uaed this validation rule
But it is not validating current month

```
AND(
ISPICKVAL( StageName , "CLOSED WON"),
HasOpportunityLineItem = FALSE,
( MONTH( CloseDate ) = MONTH(TODAY()))
)
```

what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Validation rules trigger when the rule is true. This means that you want to use a combination of AND and OR, and also that you need to check the conditions for when the error *should* occur. Also, keep in mind that months roll over every year, so you have to take that into consideration as well.

```
AND(
  ISCHANGED( StageName ),
  ISPICKVAL( StageName , "CLOSED WON"),
  OR(
    HasOpportunityLineItem, // It still has a product
    YEAR(CloseDate) < YEAR(TODAY()), // Was in a previous year
    AND( // In this year, but this month or earlier
      YEAR(CloseDate) = YEAR(TODAY()),
      MONTH(CloseDate) <= YEAR(TODAY())
    )
  )
)
```

Note that I'm reading from your "English description" of the problem. I'm not entirely sure it's what your users want (normally, users want at least one product added), but this should be exactly what you asked for, as written.

Comment: you might want to add `ISCHANGED(x)` / `ISNEW()` checks, otherwise it will "freeze the opportunity" after the month, wouldn't it? (unless that is what is expected)

Comment: @SergioAlcocer I don't disagree with that assessment. I've added it.